# Problemas con el import en Oracle: ORA-39142 numero de version incompatible con el archivo volcado

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

Tengo una consulta, tengo un archivo *dmp* (dump) de *oracle 12c*, y necesito importarlo en *11c*, pero por alguna razón, no estoy pudiendo realizar correctamente mi `import`.

Estoy ejecutando :

```
impdp usuario/password schema=nombreDelEsquema VERSION=11 DIRECTORY=dirdmp DUMPFILE=NombreDelArchivo.DMP
```

... donde `dirdmp` es un directorio que creé, indicando la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo *dump* que quiero importar.

Al correr el comando me genera el siguiente error:

> ORA-39142 : numero de version incompatible 4.1 con el archivo volcado

¿Cómo resolver este problema?

Comment: http://satishvchandran.blogspot.com.ar/2014/08/ora-39142-incompatible-version-number.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente, no se debe hacer un export/import de una versión mas nueva hacia una versión mas antigua. El problema es que el export de la versión mas nueva puede incluir objetos que ni siquiera existen en la versión mas antigua.

Me da la impresión que ya estás al tanto de este problema, y probablemente por eso intentaste agregar el parámetro `version` durante el import.

Sin embargo, no es durante el import que necesitas especificar el parámetro `version`. Mas bien, debes usar el parámetro `version` durante el **export** (`expdb`) para que el archivo *dmp* no incluya artefactos específicos a la version 12c.

Por eso, comienza por volver a ejecutar el **export** usando el parámetro `VERSION=11` tal como lo tienes. Y luego puedes volver a intentar el import.

Comment: sstan como dices intentaba eso, pero me he dado cuenta que no hay ningun camino para hacerlo de esa manera por ello hice un nuevo export para la version 11.2 y al correr el comando :

    impdp SYSTEM directory=miDirectorio dumpfile=miArchivoDump.dmp REMAP_TABLESPACE=SYSTEM:T_DATA LOGFILE=miLog.log

pero al ejecutar me dice que no se han elegido datos ni metadatos, puede ser que me falte definir alfun parametro para evitar ese error?

Comment: @Gustavo: ¿Puedes compartir el error **exacto** que recibistes, y tambiéen el comando para el export? Gracias.